# Insert table into another table conditionally - insert into select case

Tags: mysql, insert, case

I'm trying to execute a rather simple query, inserting one table (All_Shipments$Shp) into another (SC1_All_Shipments$Shp), depending on SCcount. If it is 1, insert the table, if it is not 1, do nothing.

I keep receiving the same error message:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

My code:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SC1_All_Shipments$Shp LIKE All_Shipments$Shp

    INSERT INTO SC1_All_Shipments$Shp
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN SCcount = 1 THEN '*'
            ELSE 0
        END
    FROM All_Shipments$Shp;
```

I'm not sure if the error message comes from the '*' statement. However, I've tried this with other statements and I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: Because your Select statement is returning one column. You should use where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` means that you are trying to insert a single column value in a table that has more than one column

```
INSERT INTO SC1_All_Shipments$Shp // this means that you want to put values for all SC1_All_Shipments$Shp columns
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SCcount = 1 THEN '*'
        ELSE 0
    END // ... but here you are passing only one value
FROM All_Shipments$Shp;
```

The condition about the `SCcount` field, must be placed in the `WHERE` condition in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO SC1_All_Shipments$Shp
SELECT * FROM All_Shipments$Shp
    WHERE SCcount = 1;
```

By doing this, you are selecting only data from `SC1_All_Shipments$Shp` that have `SCcount = 1` and then those datas will be inserted in `SC1_All_Shipments$Shp`.

Answer (score 2):

We can write this insert statement easily using where clause instead of case when.

```
 INSERT INTO SC1_All_Shipments$Shp
    SELECT FROM All_Shipments$Shp where SCcount = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The select that you use in insert into works like all the other Select.

It would look like thix

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SC1_All_Shipments$Shp
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
  All_Shipments$Shp
WHERE SCcount = 1;
```

You can change the where clause zo fit to your needs

Answer (score 1):

Use the `where` clause to exclude records from the insertion:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SC1_All_Shipments$Shp LIKE All_Shipments$Shp

    INSERT INTO SC1_All_Shipments$Shp
    SELECT *
    FROM All_Shipments$Shp
    WHERE SCcount = 1;
```