# Selecting into temp table dynamically with conditional source table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm preparing three temp tables and then, I assigned one of them as the data to be processed further. The choice is done by commenting out all the irrelevant temps.

```
select * into #Daily from ...
select * into #Monthly from ...
select * into #Yearly from ...
-- select * into #Data from #Daily
select * into #Data from #Montly
-- select * into #Data from #Yearly
```

Naturally, I'd like to control that by a parameter and make the selection dynamically controlled. I've only found examples [like this](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-into/) with conditions for the subset of a static source.

```
declare @Type as varchar(max) = 'Daily'
...
select * into #Data from case(...)
```

Trying different versions of the above gave me a lot of info in red color. Due to ignorance and limited competency, it's totally useless to me. (Although, I'm sure it's pretty obvious once one gets it right. It's definitely PICNIC situation.)

What should I google for? I sense it's something like *select into case source conditional* but haven't got lucky (or didn't realized that I have). Quite a lot is about **inserting into** and not **selecting into** like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030393/insert-table-into-another-table-conditionally-insert-into-select-case), which is irrelevant to me.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), if I am honest. Why not just use a single parametrised query?

Comment: The best way to do this is arguably not at all, as you are quickly heading into territory where the use of dynamic SQL is unavoidable, and combining that with temp tables is not fun. Why not have *one* table for the input, with a fixed schema?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Because I'm pulling reports and some of them are grouped on daily activity and some are on weekly or monthly. So, instead of having three separate scripts doing almost the same, I have one pulling the data and transforming it. Then, I transform the raw generic version into this or that table.

Comment: But all of them are grouped on a date/period of some kind, right? So why not use that as the basis for all of them, and then do `WHERE [Granularity] = 'Daily'`? If it's not possible to unify the schemas entirely, you will find a poor companion in T-SQL, because it hates dynamic data. `SELECT ... INTO` is an exception and an odd duck in that regard. Without entirely dynamic SQL the best you could achieve is `IF @type = 'Daily' THEN SELECT ... ELSE IF @Type = 'Monthly' THEN SELECT ...` which can still be viable, but only if almost all the query logic is done already.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think this is as far as we'll get on it due to (which I realize now) my misdirected expectations. I'm starting to see where I began to work **against** the philosophy, instead of **with** it. I'd like to see your comment as an acceptable answer. Not a satisfying one but one that is satisfying the question's context.   :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Cursor to loop through the tables and populate the Table Name from a cursor variable in some Dynamic SQL.

SSIS can also do this as everything can be parameterized including data destinations and it's perfect for this sort of workload.